# Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/compiled/semver'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run a program using react but I am facing this problem, I checked and tried many solutions none of them worked. Any help is highly appreciated[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX33P.png)

I tried many solutions none of them worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using next and next/font? I got a similar error when trying to use next/font in a project which wasn't using next

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This doesn't work. Next is probably doing some webpack magic using a require hook when loading `@next/font/google` because the normal import seems to only exist to show an error:

```
// Validate next version
const semver = require('next/dist/compiled/semver')
if (semver.lt(require('next/package.json').version, '13.0.0')) {
  throw new Error('`@next/font` is only available in Next.js 13 and newer.')
}

let message = '@next/font/google failed to run or is incorrectly configured.'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  message +=
    '\nIf you just installed `@next/font`, please try restarting `next dev` and resaving your file.'
}

message += `\n\nRead more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization`

throw new Error(message)
```

---

`@next/font` doesn't include `next` in its `package.json#peerDependencies`. If you are using pnpm and not in flatten-shamelessly mode, then `next` won't be found.

You can add it using https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmpackageextensions

```
    "packageExtensions": {
      "@next/font": {
        "peerDependencies": {
          "next": "*"
        }
      },
```

---

*/pages/index.tsx*

```
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
```

*/node_modules/@next/font/google/index.js*

```
const semver = require('next/dist/compiled/semver')
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44498